# getResources () java android game code

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to set color on my android game the code i am using is:

//Draw the board....

```
//Define colours for grid lines
    Paint hilite = new Paint();
    hilite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game_hilite));
    Paint light = new Paint();
    light.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game_light));
    Paint dark = new Paint();
    dark.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game_dark));``
```

i have set up the color in the color.xml code as:

```
<resources>
  <color name="game_background">#ffe6f0ff</color>
    <color name="game_hilite">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="game_light">#64c6d4ef</color>
    <color name="game_dark">#6456648f</color>
    <color name="game_foreground">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="game_selected">#64ff8000</color>
</resources>`
```

just cant seem to see where is going wrong, the code in bold is where i seem to be getting the issues multi marker errors.

the full code section i have is:

```
         @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Draw the background...
        Paint background = new Paint();
        background.setColor(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.game_background));
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);

        //Draw the board
        //Draw the selection
    }

    //Draw the board....
    //Define colours for grid lines
    Paint hilite = new Paint();
    hilite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game_hilite));
    Paint light = new Paint();
    light.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game_light));
    Paint dark = new Paint();
    dark.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game_dark));


    //Draw the minor grid lines
    Canvas canvas;
    for (int i = 0; i <9; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, light);
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1, hilite);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), light);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(), hilite);  
    }
    //Draw the major grid lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i % 3 != 0)
            continue;
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, dark);
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1, hilite);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), dark);
        canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(), hilite);
    }
```

}

Comment: Where is your Java code located?

Comment: From wich context are you calling getResources()?

Comment: Learn how to format your code..

Comment: What's the problem you're having? Is it crashing? Are your colours wrong?

Comment: it wont run at all saying "Return type for the method is missing"

Comment: the java code is located with the src file

Comment: @JulieFlatman Post your code here..

Comment: what part of the code as there is quite a bit. just that java file or all related code ?

Comment: @JulieFlatman if Possible post your class code, or Post Atlest method where you are getting the error...

Comment: above is where i am getting the error: hilite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game_hilite)); this is the line i am having problems with

Comment: Whichever method the above is in has a missing return type. Check your Java syntax.

Comment: @JulieFlatman a method definition will start from { and ends with } , please post entire method..

Comment: i have added the section that is causing the error to the main post.

Comment: move your code outside of onDraw to inside of onDraw

Comment: this then gives me issues with the //Draw the minor grid lines
    Canvas canvas; section

Comment: From what I see there is a extra '}' right after 'Draw the selection' which could be the reason you are not able to run the code.